# Does time.h Allow Leap Years C

Tags: c, date, time

I am looking for a way to find the difference between two dates. The solution needs to take into account leap years. Please see the two blocks of code below. 2012 was a leap year whereas 2013 was not, and so I fail to understand why both programs output "32 days difference". Surely they should be different if time.h does indeed take into account leap years?

The first:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <time.h>       
int main ()
{
  struct tm start_date;
  struct tm end_date;
  time_t start_time, end_time;
  double days;

  start_date.tm_hour = 0;  start_date.tm_min = 0;  start_date.tm_sec = 0;
  start_date.tm_mon = 2; start_date.tm_mday = 1; start_date.tm_year = 112;

  end_date.tm_hour = 0;  end_date.tm_min = 0;  end_date.tm_sec = 0;
  end_date.tm_mon = 3; end_date.tm_mday = 1; end_date.tm_year = 112;

  start_time = mktime(&start_date);
  end_time = mktime(&end_date);

  days = difftime(end_time, start_time) / 86400;

  printf ("%.f days difference\n", days);

  return 0;
}
```

The second:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <time.h>       
int main ()
{
  struct tm start_date;
  struct tm end_date;
  time_t start_time, end_time;
  double days;

  start_date.tm_hour = 0;  start_date.tm_min = 0;  start_date.tm_sec = 0;
  start_date.tm_mon = 2; start_date.tm_mday = 1; start_date.tm_year = 113;

  end_date.tm_hour = 0;  end_date.tm_min = 0;  end_date.tm_sec = 0;
  end_date.tm_mon = 3; end_date.tm_mday = 1; end_date.tm_year = 113;

  start_time = mktime(&start_date);
  end_time = mktime(&end_date);

  days = difftime(end_time, start_time) / 86400;

  printf ("%.f days difference\n", days);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be careful, because you declare the structures as local variables but don't initialize all fields in them. That means the values of the uninitialized fields will be indeterminate and the result of the `mktime` calls will be undefined.

Comment: Also note that the months you enter is March and April. The `tm_mon` member field is zero-based, where one is February and two is March. See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you very much, that was what was wrong I think, it works now. However, I don't really understand your first comment, could you expand?

Comment: Local variables (i.e. variables declared inside functions) are not initialized by the compiler. When they have been defined but not initialized their values are indeterminate, and using them without initialization (i.e. assigning to them) leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Of course this goes for array and structure variables as well as simple integer or floating point variables. To initialize a structure variable, do e.g. `struct tm start_date = { 0 };`, or make sure you initialize *all* members in the structure.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So which other ones do I have to initialize? Also, how come the come works when I change mday to 0?

Comment: Why are you using `112` and `113` as years when you really mean `2012` and `2013`?

Comment: @Floris I linked to [a `struct tm` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm) before. I suggest you read it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - thanks. I should rtfm more... I knew that 1900 was the "start of time" in some systems - it had not occurred to me that the user interface would use "years to that date" rather than translate to "real" years. I guess you are expected to use higher level functions to interact with this function rather than work at the structure element level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buddy just try the following (change your month as 1 and 2 respectively instead of 2 and 3, it will give you correct results, this change is tested).

As per Joachim and Floris,
Month is zero based for tm_mon member, and you were counting the difference between March 1 and April 1 instead of Feb 1 and Mar 1.

```
  start_date.tm_hour = 0;  start_date.tm_min = 0;  start_date.tm_sec = 0;
  start_date.tm_mon = 1; start_date.tm_mday = 1; start_date.tm_year = 112;

  end_date.tm_hour = 0;  end_date.tm_min = 0;  end_date.tm_sec = 0;
  end_date.tm_mon = 2; end_date.tm_mday = 1; end_date.tm_year = 112;
```

Comment: You are identifying the correct problem. It might be worth a few lines of explanation - i.e. "months start at zero, and you were counting the difference between March 1 and April 1 instead of Feb 1 and Mar 1" or some such.